# Copy Pandas DataFrame using '=' trick

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas DataFrames, `sdm`. I wanted to create a copy of that DataFrame and work on that and later, I want to create another copy from `sdm` and work on different analysis. However, when I create a new Data Frame like this,

```
new_df = sdm
```

It creates a copy, however, when I alter `new_df`, it makes changes to the my old DataFrame `sdm`. How can I handle this without using `=`?

Comment: To copy a dataframe: `sdm.copy()`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html.  You probably want a deep copy, too, so don't forget `deep=True`.

Comment: May I ask you why `=` does not work as it is in `R`?

Comment: You might want to look at ["Facts and myths about Python names and values" (Blog post by Ned Batchelder)](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) already the third "fact" is appropriate here "Fact: Many names can refer to one value.". In short: `=` isn't a trick. It's an assignment. It assigns the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side.

Comment: @MSeifert got it, thank you, I will read that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What python does is passing by reference. Try this:

```
new_df = sdm.copy()
```

I think you should have search more, I am sure there will be lots of questions on this topic!

Comment: I know I should have searched more, but I was confused why this was happening. as @PaSTE pointed I used `deep=True` too and it works!

Comment: @Jesse as mentioned in the answer, there is plenty of information online for this question. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `new_df = sdm.copy()` instead which is described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) in the official documentation. `new_df = sdm` doesn't work because this assignement operation performs a copy by reference and not by value which means in nutshell, both `new_df` and `sdm` will reference the same data in memory.